# Problema para crear saltos de línea

Tags: php, html, echo

estoy haciendo un script muy sencillo que practicamente recoge datos de un formulario y los "imprime en pantalla" mediante "echo" de PHP con un formato predefinido.

Sin embargo necesito que haya unos saltos de linea en blanco pero estos no los "imprime" se los come.

Cómo puedo hacer para que esto suceda.

Les muestro un ejemplo:

El código que uso para que se muestre el resultado es el siguiente

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['url1'])&&
    isset($_POST['url2'])&&
    isset($_POST['url3'])&&
    isset($_POST['url4'])&&
    isset($_POST['url5'])&&
    isset($_POST['url6'])&&
    isset($_POST['url7'])&&
    isset($_POST['url8'])&&
    isset($_POST['url9'])&&
    isset($_POST['url10'])&&
    isset($_POST['url11'])&&
    isset($_POST['url12'])&&
    isset($_POST['url13'])&&
    isset($_POST['url14'])&&
    isset($_POST['url15'])&&
    isset($_POST['url16'])&&
    isset($_POST['url17'])&&
    isset($_POST['url18'])&&
    isset($_POST['url19'])&&
    isset($_POST['url20'])&&
    isset($_POST['url21'])
    )
{
    echo "Resultado:". "<br><br><br><br><br>";

    $line   ='[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button='.$_POST['url1'].']S01 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button='.$_POST['url2'].']Parte 2[/button]';

    echo "<br><br><br>";

    $line  .='[img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button='.$_POST['url3'].']S02 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button='.$_POST['url4'].']Parte 2[/button]';
```

Como pueden ver use "`echo "<br><br><br>";`" en un intento porque imprima los saltos de linea pero lo imprime de la siguiente forma

```
[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]S01 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]Parte 2[/button][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]S02 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]Parte 2[/button][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]S03 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]Parte 2[/button][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]S04 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]Parte 2[/button][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]S05 Parte 1[/button] | [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img] [button=http://google.com/1]Parte 2[/button][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img]
```

Como pueden ver no hay saltos de línea, que puedo hacer para que los respete?

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solición brindada es:

```
 $line  .= '<br>'
```

Ya que confundía el echo y tenía que usar $line

Gracias a todos :)